# Remove left and right string in php and replace

Tags: php, string, replace

hi everyone i have problem. i have the code like this

```
$foo = array(':1:',':2:',':3:4:');
```

and I want the result is like this

```
$foo = array('1','2','3,4');
```

thank's before for help :)
sorry for my english

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/array_map) with a callback using [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) will do the trick:

```
$foo = array_map(function($val) {
    $val = trim($val, ':');
    return str_replace(':', ',', $val);
}, $foo);
```

Comment: You beat me by 18 seconds, congratulations :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/array_map) function to traverse and modify an array:

```
$foo = array_map(function($v) {
    return str_replace(':', ',', trim($v, ':'));
}, $foo);
```

I'm assuming you want to trim off leading and trailing colons and convert the others to commas. Your question isn't very clear in describing requirements.